# Apache ignoring ServerName and ServerAlias - running using precedence

Tags: apache, virtualhost, operator-precedence

Apache is ignoring ServerName and ServerAlias for my main VirtualHost entry.

My scenario:

```
- main domain is "one.com" (just an example)
- secondary domains are several, pointing to the same IP of "one.com", but they need
to be in a different VirtualHost entry, so I can redirect to "one.com" using PHP
(I want to log redirects).
```

So, I did:

```
<VirtualHost 208.1.2.3:80>
    DocumentRoot /sites/redir
    ErrorLog logs/redir-error_log
    CustomLog logs/redir-access_log common
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 208.1.2.3:80>
    DocumentRoot /sites/main
    ServerName one.com
    ServerAlias www.one.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    ErrorLog logs/main-error_log
    CustomLog logs/main-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Due to precedence, any domain different of one.com will use the first entry, that does not have ServerName nor ServerAlias.

The problem: ALL requests go to the first entry, including one.com and www.one.com what causes an infinite loop, since my PHP script redirects to one.com. If I invert the blocks, all requests go to the "main" entry...

What I need is that one.com and www.one.com runs in /sites/main and any other domain goes to /sites/redir to be redirected to the "one.com" entry.

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Arvy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED.

The problem is that the first "global" entry NEEDS ServerName parameter. You dont need to inform a valid entry, just need something on it, like "ServerName mask.one.com". This way, put the first entry as the "generic" one and the second with the valid domain(s), in my case, one.com. Any domains that are not listed will use precedence, so, will run like "mask.one.com".

```
<VirtualHost 208.1.2.3:80>
    DocumentRoot /sites/redir
    ServerName redir.one.com
    ErrorLog logs/redir-error_log
    CustomLog logs/redir-access_log common
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 208.1.2.3:80>
    DocumentRoot /sites/main
    ServerName one.com
    ServerAlias www.one.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    ErrorLog logs/main-error_log
    CustomLog logs/main-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```